# Unable to cache icon warning, when building notification

Tags: android, notifications, xamarin.android, android-theme, cyanogenmod

I'm using notification in my app that displays progress, and i have build a class the can easily handle the notification update for me.

For the constructor i pass a context, in order to be able to build the notification. Here is the method for updating a progress notification:

```
public void ReportProgress(int percentage, string title, string content, int icon = Resource.Drawable.Icon)
{

    builder = new Notification.Builder(c)
        .SetContentText(content)
        .SetContentTitle(title)
        .SetSmallIcon(icon)
        .SetProgress(100, percentage, false)
        .SetOngoing(true);

    notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, builder.Build());
}
```

I keep the same notification ID, so i can update the existing notification, and not create new ones.I have seen the warning show up also with regular notification , but it's most noticeable with the progress, since there are a lot more updates.

Here is the log of the warning :

```
09-19 11:49:44.754 W/IconPackHelper(17467): Unable to cache icon /data/system/theme/icons/com.App_7f020002_0.png
09-19 11:49:44.806 W/IconPackHelper(17467): Unable to cache icon /data/system/theme/icons/com.App_7f020002_0.png
09-19 11:49:44.863 W/IconPackHelper(17467): Unable to cache icon /data/system/theme/icons/com.App_7f020002_0.png
09-19 11:49:44.887 W/IconPackHelper(17467): Unable to cache icon /data/system/theme/icons/com.App_7f020002_0.png
09-19 11:49:44.940 W/IconPackHelper(17467): Unable to cache icon /data/system/theme/icons/com.App_7f020002_0.png
09-19 11:49:44.973 W/IconPackHelper(17467): Unable to cache icon /data/system/theme/icons/com.App_7f020002_0.png
09-19 11:49:45.006 W/IconPackHelper(17467): Unable to cache icon /data/system/theme/icons/com.App_7f020002_0.png
09-19 11:49:45.051 W/IconPackHelper(17467): Unable to cache icon /data/system/theme/icons/com.App_7f020002_0.png
09-19 11:49:45.089 W/IconPackHelper(17467): Unable to cache icon /data/system/theme/icons/com.App_7f020002_0.png
09-19 11:49:45.127 W/IconPackHelper(17467): Unable to cache icon /data/system/theme/icons/com.App_7f020002_0.png
09-19 11:49:45.175 W/IconPackHelper(17467): Unable to cache icon /data/system/theme/icons/com.App_7f020002_0.png
09-19 11:49:45.232 W/IconPackHelper(17467): Unable to cache icon /data/system/theme/icons/com.App_7f020002_0.png
09-19 11:49:45.291 W/IconPackHelper(17467): Unable to cache icon /data/system/theme/icons/com.App_7f020002_0.png
09-19 11:49:45.336 W/IconPackHelper(17467): Unable to cache icon /data/system/theme/icons/com.App_7f020002_0.png
09-19 11:49:45.372 W/IconPackHelper(17467): Unable to cache icon /data/system/theme/icons/com.App_7f020002_0.png
```

Important Note this warning only shows up when i'm **testing it on my real phone, which is nexus 5 running cyanogen mod 13, running the latest update  cm-13.0-20160921-NIGHTLY**,i have used multiple emulators and the error is not occurring there.I haven't had the chance to test it on another phone with cyanoegenmod.

It goes everytime i update the notification (100+). How can i stop this error ? Why is it happening ? Should it concern me ?

### EDIT

I have confirmed that IconPackHelper is a part of the cyanogenmod theme service,here is the source for it [IconCacheManagerService](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_services_ThemeManagerService/blob/cm-13.0/src/org/cyanogenmod/themeservice/IconCacheManagerService.java).

Here is the actual log from logcat, its crashing because it doesn't have the permission (?) to access the file.

```
09-21 16:33:44.002: W/IconCacheManagerService(6389): Unable to cache icon com.App_7f020002_0.png
09-21 16:33:44.002: W/IconCacheManagerService(6389): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/theme/icons/com.App_7f020002_0.png: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
09-21 16:33:44.002: W/IconCacheManagerService(6389):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
09-21 16:33:44.002: W/IconCacheManagerService(6389):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
09-21 16:33:44.002: W/IconCacheManagerService(6389):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72)
09-21 16:33:44.002: W/IconCacheManagerService(6389):    at org.cyanogenmod.themeservice.IconCacheManagerService$2.cacheComposedIcon(IconCacheManagerService.java:75)
09-21 16:33:44.002: W/IconCacheManagerService(6389):    at org.cyanogenmod.internal.themes.IIconCacheManager$Stub.onTransact(IIconCacheManager.java:58)
09-21 16:33:44.002: W/IconCacheManagerService(6389):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
09-21 16:33:44.002: W/IconCacheManagerService(6389): Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
09-21 16:33:44.002: W/IconCacheManagerService(6389):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
09-21 16:33:44.002: W/IconCacheManagerService(6389):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
09-21 16:33:44.002: W/IconCacheManagerService(6389):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
09-21 16:33:44.002: W/IconCacheManagerService(6389):    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Who is `IconPackHelper`? Is it your class or its a part of some 3rd party lib?

Comment: I dont know what IconPackHelper is, its not a lib/ class that i wrote, it must be something from the os

Answer (score -1):

you are use a phone with cyanogenMod?

Comment: Yes, nexus 5 running cm13

Comment: you can try  your code on another device without cyanogenmod or try on a emulator and see if the error persists

Comment: Well, i wrote that on the emulator it doesn't do that, and i dont have access to another phone right now, one thing i can think of is updating the build, which i will test tomorrow